# How to control rendering of multiple checkboxes in a "b-form-checkbox-group"

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have this Vue code:

```
<b-input-group >
   <b-form-checkbox-group id="boxes"
      v-model="selectedBoxes"
      :options="boxes"
      name="boxes"
      stacked />
</b-input-group>

// my data() includes returning:
boxes: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
selectedBoxes: [],
```

producing this rendering (due to the `stacked`).  I would prefer to have the checkboxes two wide, in a stack of only three.  Is that easy to new (new to Vue).

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your checkboxes to be inline if there are three or less, and stacked if there are more than three, you can do the following:

```html
<b-input-group >
   <b-form-checkbox-group id="boxes"
      v-model="selectedBoxes"
      :options="boxes"
      name="boxes"
      :stacked="boxes.length > 3" />
</b-input-group>
```

This makes `stacked` = `true` when there are more than three checkboxes, otherwise it renders the checkboxes inline (`stacked` = `false`).

Or use CSS columns to render the stacked checkboxes in columnar format, regardless of the number of checkboxes:

```html
<b-input-group >
   <b-form-checkbox-group id="boxes"
      v-model="selectedBoxes"
      style="column-count: 2;"
      :options="boxes"
      name="boxes"
      stacked />
</b-input-group>
```

Just change `column-count` to the number of columns you would like. For more info on CSS columns, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

[image: example checkbox columns]

Comment: Thank you for both!  The CSS style works perfectly for me though!!!

Comment: You could also create a custom class that sets the number of columns based on media queries as well (e.g. 4 columns for `lg` screens and up, 3 columns for `md` screens, 2 columns for `sm` screens and 1 column for `xs` screens)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way to do this using a `b-checkbox-group`.

You can instead use a `v-for` with individual `b-checkbox` and a computed property to get the selected values.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    selectedBoxes() {
      return this.boxes.filter(box => box.checked).map(box => box.value);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      boxes: [
        { value: 1, text: 'Value 1', checked: false },
        { value: 2, text: 'Value 2', checked: false },
        { value: 3, text: 'Value 3', checked: false },
        { value: 4, text: 'Value 4', checked: false },
        { value: 5, text: 'Value 5', checked: false },
        { value: 6, text: 'Value 6', checked: false }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body { padding: 1rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="font-weight-bold">
    Using span and br
  </div>
  <span v-for="(box, index) in boxes">
    <b-checkbox :key="index" v-model="box.checked" class="d-inline">
      {{ box.text }}
    </b-checkbox>

    <!-- Render a <br> every 2nd checkbox -->
    <br v-if="index % 2" />
  </span>
  
  <!-- 
     Another option is to use the bootstrap grid system.
     However this will create spacing between the elements based on the width of the row
    -->
  <div class="font-weight-bold mt-5">
    Using row/cols
  </div>
  <b-row>
    <b-col v-for="(box, index) in boxes" cols="6">
      <b-checkbox :key="index" v-model="box.checked">
        {{ box.text }}
      </b-checkbox>
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
  Selected boxes: {{ selectedBoxes.length > 0 ? selectedBoxes : 'Nothing selected' }}
</div>
```